# Separate data containing digits and non digits

Tags: string, r, digits

I have a character vector:

```
A <- c("terrestrial human",
       "animal 7 planet",
       "geographic 23 locations",
       "discovery kids")
```

I want to separate this into two vectors: one has all the entries containing digits, and the other containing data without any digits.

```
v1 <- c("animal 7 planet","geographic 23 locations") 
v2 <- c("terrestrial human","discovery kids")
```

Comment: Have you tried using `grepl`?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: You seem to have a vector. `x <- c("terrestrial human", "animal 7 planet","geographic 23 locations","discovery kids") ;split( x , grepl( "[0-9]" , m ) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty of declaring `Matrix A` as a vector called `A` instead, since it seems to be one dimensional -

```
A[!grepl(x = A, pattern = '[[:digit:]]')]
A[grepl(x = A, pattern = '[[:digit:]]')]
```